# Mongoose return fields order inconsistent

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a very simple mongoose query, that returns correctly but the field display ordering is not consistent.  Notice how sometimes it lists _id and then username and sometimes it lists username and then _id.  Any way to fix this?

```
exports.list = function(req, res){
    return db.userModel.find({}, 'username', function (err, users) {
         if(!err) {
             return res.json(users);
         } else {
            console.log(err);
            return res.send(400);
        }
    });
 }
```

Output

```
[
  {
    "username": "admin",
    "_id": "5145293a420135521c000001"
  },
  {
    "username": "bob",
    "_id": "5145293b420135521c000002"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5145293b420135521c000003",
    "username": "example"
  }
]
```

Comment: Objects in JavaScript are *not* ordered collections. There is no given guarantee or a way to create one for the order in which keys are iterated. The engine can even shuffle what order it has them in in memory if it needs to.

Comment: why is the order important?

Comment: I guess it's not, just for an api when I open it up in the browser it would be nice if they were all consistent.  Is there any way to accept the comment as an answer?