# JSON response from mongoose query showing up out of order

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have the following mongoose schema

```
const analyticsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  All_Rehires_Processed: Number,
  All_Unique_Rehires_Processed: Number,
  Files_Generated: Number,
  Files_Generated_By_Position: {
    Core: {
      Server: {
        Server0: Number,
        Server1: Number,
        Server2: Number,
        Server3: Number
      }
    },
    Nop: {
      Server: {
        Server0: Number,
        Server1: Number,
        Server2: Number,
        Server3: Number
      }
    }
  },
  Rehires_By_Position: {
    Core: {
      Server: {
        Server0: Number,
        Server1: Number,
        Server2: Number,
        Server3: Number
      }
    },
    Nop: {
      Server: {
        Server0: Number,
        Server1: Number,
        Server2: Number,
        Server3: Number
      }
    }
  }
});
```

When I check the data in the database it returns the results in the correct order.
I run

```
db.getCollection('analytics').find({}).pretty()
```

It returns the correct order.

```
{
  "_id": "5bdeafda975df6b565bfed2a",
  "All_Rehires_Processed": 137,
  "All_Unique_Rehires_Processed": 108,
  "Files_Generated": 41,
  "Files_Generated_By_Position": {
    "Core": {
      "Server": {
        "Server0": 1,
        "Server1": 1,
        "Server2": 1,
        "Server3": 1
      }
    },
    "Nop": {
      "Server": {
        "Server0": 0,
        "Server1": 1,
        "Server2": 1,
        "Server3": 1
      }
    }
  },
  "Rehires_By_Position": {
    "Core": {
      "Server": {
        "Server0": 30,
        "Server1": 30,
        "Server2": 14,
        "Server3": 11

      }
    },
    "Nop": {
      "Server": {
        "Server0": 0,
        "Server1": 1,
        "Server2": 1,
        "Server3": 1
      }
    }
  },
  "__v": 0
}
```

I am currently returning data to an express endpoint

```
app.get('/analytics', (req, res) => {
  Analytics.find({}, (err, analytics) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    // check if analytics
    if (!analytics || analytics.length === 0) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        error: 'No files exist'
      });
    }
    //analytics exist
    return res.json(analytics);
  });
});
```

This works and returns the data i expect but in the wrong order. It returns the data in the following order

```
{
  "Files_Generated_By_Position": {
    "Core": {
      "Server": {
        "Server0": 1,
        "Server1": 1,
        "Server2": 1,
        "Server3": 1
      }
    },
    "Nop": {
      "Server": {
        "Server0": 0,
        "Server1": 1,
        "Server2": 1,
        "Server3": 1
      }
    }
  },
  "Rehires_By_Position": {
    "Core": {
      "Server": {
        "Server0": 30,
        "Server1": 30,
        "Server2": 14,
        "Server3": 11

      }
    },
    "Nop": {
      "Server": {
        "Server0": 0,
        "Server1": 1,
        "Server2": 1,
        "Server3": 1
      }
    }
  },
  "_id": "5bdeafda975df6b565bfed2a",
  "All_Rehires_Processed": 137,
  "All_Unique_Rehires_Processed": 108,
  "Files_Generated": 41,
  "__v": 0
}
```

Is there any way to enforce the json object maintains order when returning to the express endpoint? Do I have to sort it or is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: yes why don't you just specify sort order?

Comment: i don't think order matter in the object Although just look at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15456994/mongoose-return-fields-order-inconsistent